# Force stopping bloatware apps on android phone

Tags: force-stop

I don't use Facebook and don't intend to. Can I force stop on android phone (LG Stylo 4) without destabilizing anything else? I have installed WhatsApp which I know is owned by Facebook but which I think (hope) functions independently and hopefully would not be impacted by stopping Facebook.

Comment: You ca simply disable and/or deinstall the Facebook app. That will permanently stop it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WhatsApps runs separately from Facebook, despite them being owned by the same company. You can safely force stop Facebook.

If you don't intend to use Facebook, the more logical solution is to remove it, which will prevent it from doing anything and free up space.